# Is the public domain revocable?

Tags: intellectual-property, public-domain

If a work enters the public domain, can someone "privatize" it by trying to copyright/trademark/etc. the same work without changes?

Answer (score 2):

Under US copyright law, there are two statutory provisions that correspond to "being in the public domain". The first is that [US government works](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/105) are not protected by copyright, therefore they are "in the public domain". The second is that copyright has a [specific duration](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/chapter-3), so if a work is "too old" in that defined sense, it is also "in the public domain" and is not protected by copyright. In either event, copyright is a right held by the author, and "is a US government work" is "is too old" is an immutable fact that cannot be revoked.

The third possibility is via a "public domain license", whereby an author declares that anybody is free to use their work – like an ordinary license, without the "in consideration of X I permit you to Y" verbiage. A bare license is generally revocable, ergo you can enter my bar without my explicit permission, but I can revoke that license to enter. It has not been definitively settled by the courts whether a bare copyright license is revocable, instead licenses usually include some quid pro quo condition that makes the license be a contract. There are also statutory provisions allowing for the eventual [termination of a license](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/203), so this third path is not a definitive entry into the public domain.

Regardless of the "public domain" status of a work, copyright only arises from creating a work, therefore if a person creates nothing, there is nothing protected by copyright. You cannot try to / fail to copyright a work, because the right known as "copyright" is automatic with the creation of the work. Registration of copyright is completely separate act, and does not create a copyright (though it is a necessary act in order to sue a person for copyright infringement).

Answer (score 0):

### Copyright is unrecoverable

You don't gain copyright for publishing a work. You only gain copyright when you **make** a work. Once copyright lapses because the author is dead long enough or the corporate work was published long enough ago, that's it. Nobody can have copyright in *this* one work.

### Trademark does not privatize a work

Trademark is to identify the origin of a product that is used in commerce. For example, Coca Cola. **Some** trademarks share names with IP, but they only extend to the trademark, not the works: [There's a Conan holding that owns multiple Conan trademarks](https://trademarks.justia.com/owners/conan-properties-international-llc-2793904/), but the works by Robert E. Howard are still out of copyright. You can re-publish the Conan stories, but can't infringe on those trademarks.

### Separate works have separate copyright.

I mentioned     Robert E. Howard and Conan for a reason: while the *stories* by Howard are out of copyright and public domain as are the characters with it, the adaptions like the 1982 and 1984 films are still under copyright. Those are **separate** works, they have separate copyright.